# Déjà Dub "Restore Failure"

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I keep on getting the following failure while trying to restore my back up:

> Backup location ‘/media/rick/3D8A-5060/duplicity-full.20140102T163252Z.vol445.difftar.gz’ does not exist

I understand that there's a file missing, but what can I do to force Déjà Dup to continue restoring? Because, the process stops midway, but my most important files aren't yet restored by then.

Or does this error message mean that all files, besides the ones already restored, have gone?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a few months old now, but for future reference, Deja-Dup allow you to restore in individual folders. In your file manager (default Nautilus), right-click in the folder you want to restore to and select "Restore missing files", Deja-Dup will restore only to that folder instead of trying to restore the entire backup.

I've noticed Deja-Dup will throw that error incorrectly. Assuming you're using an external drive, unplug your drive, close Deja-Dup and start the process again. For some reason it works on subsequent tries.

Lastly, there is a restore method using terminal with Deja-Dup using the "duplicity" command to list and restore your files that you really need. I'll have to edit this post later so I can share the link.

EDIT: The link is here: [deja dup backup restore has failed me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422872/deja-dup-backup-restore-has-failed-me)