# Restore fails deja dup

Tags: 16.04

I backed up my home folder with deja dup. I then reinstall Ubuntu 16.04. After all updates and software installation, I tried to restore my backup with no luck.
It hangs saying input and output error

Comment: More info please-where is the backup located, exact text of error, etc.

Comment: Backed up in external hardrive and error message is Backup location ‘/duplicity-full.20160502T184526Z.vol5764.difftar.gz’ does not exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/422872/deja-dup-backup-restore-has-failed-me  See here for workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to reload my Documents, Pictures, and Videos files. I saved my backup to 16Gbyte USB stick under 14.04 LTS. Somehow the folder were I placed the backup got placed under a different directory on the USB stick. Try looking around in the directory, or on the device where you stored the backup. Once I got the correct path to the backup, deja dup worked and restored my files to those directories under 16.04 LTS.